# inputCurrency format changes on focus

Tags: javascript, lightning, bug, currency

I have an inputCurrency field defined like this:

```
<ui:inputCurrency aura:id="amount" class="slds-p-top_none" value="{!s.Amount__c}"/>
```

This input is inside a component that lives inside an Opportunity record.
I set the format based on the Opportunity's CurrencyIsoCode and it changes it correctly when the component loads.

This is the function I use to change the format, this runs on init (the inputs that I want to change format have "amount" as an id):

```
updateCurrency : function(component, opportunity) {

    if(opportunity.hasOwnProperty("CurrencyIsoCode")) {
        var curr = component.find("amount");
        console.log(curr);
        console.log(opportunity);
        curr.forEach((c) => {
            //console.log(opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode);
            switch(opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode) {
                case 'EUR':
                    //console.log('EUR');
                    c.set("v.format", '€#,###.00');
                break;
                case 'USD':
                    //console.log('USD');
                    c.set("v.format", '$#,###.00');
                break;
                case 'JPY':
                    console.log('JPY');
                    c.set("v.format", '¥#,###.00');
                break;
                case 'GBP':
                    c.set("v.format", '£#,###.00');
                break;
                default:
                    c.set("v.format", opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode + '#,###.00');

            }
        });  
        console.log('done');
    }
}
```

However, when I modify the input's value and lose focus, the currency format symbol changes to "$" despite the CurrencyIsoCode.

Also, I'm not running anything on the inputCurrency focus.

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you set updateOn attribute on handler ?

Comment: Nope, the only place I modify the input is in that function which is called on init.